# Default Styling for text blocks in an MVVM application

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have run across a problem when overriding default styles in an MVVM . I am trying to change the default foreground value of all of the text in my application. This works until I have Text Blocks in UserControls. These Text Blocks do not inherit from the default, unlike the other controls such as Labels.

I have created a small example for this.

I have a generic Resource dictionary declared. This is holding the default styles.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Resources">
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="Blue" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

This resource dictionary is merged into the MainWindow.

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControlViewModel}">
            <v:UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Grid>
    <Label>Main Window Label</Label>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Main Window Text Block</TextBlock>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

In my simple example I have a generic MainViewModel set to the DataContext of the MainWindow.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public UserControlViewModel Content { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Content = new UserControlViewModel();
    }
}
```

The user control viewmodel is simply a shell with no properties that need to be displayed. However the user control itself is just a simple label and text block like the Main Window

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Label>UserControl Label</Label>
        <TextBlock >User Control Text Block</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The weird part is the override for the Label works properly and the Text Block does not. This is the picture of the end result.

[image]

Why does the Text Block in the user control not use the default style that is applied to the Text Block?

Comment: if you want to use a global custom style place it in your app.xaml and not in your window resources

Comment: @Joh. Thanks, That did it for me. Do you by chance understand why the label would tunnel down through user controls but not the TextBlock?

Comment: @MattWilkinson WPF treats a `ControlTemplate` as a boundary for applying implicit styles, *except* in the case of styles defined in `Application.Resources`, which should be global. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7617502/302677) for some details and exceptions to this rule.