# No Style Inheritance Inside ItemsControl / DataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

can anyone explain why the `TextBlock` inside my `DataTemplate` does not apply the style defined in my `UserControl.Resources` element, but the second `TextBlock` ('Test B') does?

I think it may have to do with a dependency property somewhere set to not inherit, but I can't be sure.

```
<UserControl.Resources>       
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 2" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">         
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--Padding does not apply--> 
                <TextBlock>Test A</TextBlock>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!--Padding applies-->
    <TextBlock>Test B</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my TextBlock/TextBox apply values from a Base Style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597455/why-doesnt-my-textblock-textbox-apply-values-from-a-base-style)

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but if you give the style an x:Key and then apply it as static resource it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templates are considered as a boundary. Elements within the templates falls in this boundary range, and look up for the style with a matching target type ends within this range at runtime as a result the `TextBlock` outside will pickup the style and the one inside wont. like adminSoftDK said you should `give the style an x:Key and then apply it as static resource it will work`.